# Proving properties of rational exponents based on definition in Tom Apostol's Calculus

Tags: calculus

From Tom Apostol's *Calculus*. I have been stuck at this statement :

> If $r$ is a positive rational number , say $r = m/n$ , where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, we define $x^r = (x^m)^{(1/n)}$ . If $x$ is not $0$ , then we define $x^{(-r)} = 1/(x^r)$ whenever $x^r$ is defined. From there, it is easy to verify these laws : $$x^r \cdot x^s = x^{(r+s)} ,$$ $$(x^r)^s = x^{(r\cdot s)}, $$$$ (xy)^r = x^r \cdot y^r.$$

I solved the second law by his definition , but don't know how to solve the others, and I searched on Google but still can't find out . Can you give me a hint ? Or I must use other stuff that's not in this definition ?

Comment: Has he proved yet that $x^r$ is well defined?  In other words, for any of this to make sense you need to show that if $\frac ab = \frac mn$, then this definition gives the same result for $x^{a/b}$ and $x^{m/n}$.  A slight modification of that proof should get you where you need to be.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Apostol on hand so I can't reference what he's already proved, but presumably for the first one you want to express $r+s$ as a ratio of integers.  If $r=a/b$ and $s=c/d$ for appropriate integers $a,b,c,d$ then $r+s=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$.  Now $x^{r+s} = (x^{ad+bc})^{1/(bd)}$.  This must be progress right?

From here, it makes sense to show that $x^r\cdot x^s$ has the desired property.  What is the desired property?  The property demanded by "roots", i.e. that $1/(bd)$ in the outer exponent.  So the desired property is that

$$(x^r\cdot x^s)^{bd} = x^{ad+bc}$$

This is what you now want to prove.  Can you take it from here?

(At least I would assume that this is how you define roots.  Again, I don't have Apostol on hand to confirm, but I think this makes sense.)